# How to reference an announcement list item?

Tags: list, spservices

When I look at the url at a given announcement list on e.g. a fresh team site, it is something like:

`http://xyz/_layouts/listform.apsx?PageType=4&ListId={B3352....}&ID=4&ContentTypeID=0x010...`

What I am trying is to link to a specific item in the list. Via SPServices I get the ID of the item easily - what I can't find is the ListId. I tried the **GetList - operation** but the "ID" which is given in that url is not the one I am looking for.

At which place is this ListId exposed?

**EDIT:**
To make it more clear what I am coping with: The items in the announcement list all open with the URL I have provided above. What I can't find so far is the "ListId" value, in my actual case it is "{B3352...}". I already tried to get this ListId via SPServices GetList-operation but the value of the attribute "ID" from the returning XML shows a different ID {622C14...}. I looked at all the XML output and there is no value like the one I am looking for "{B3352...}" though I used the same code as already mentioned by [yaron](http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/jquery-spservice-get-list-guid/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an error on my first approach and finally got the solution:

Unfortunately I didn't pass the **webURL** parameter on the GetListId function. So my result was nonesense.

The actual solution where to get the ListId from, I used the **GetList**-operation and parse for the **Name**-attribute:

```
var listId = $(xData.responseXML).find("List").attr("Name");
```

To add more detail to my overall topic, here is my final approach:

## Final link structure

List

- ListId - as mentioned above
- ID - ID of the announcement item, got it through GetListItems $(this).attr("ows_ID")

### Open Announcement in modal window

As users expect announcements to open in modal windows I added the following click event to my link element

```
onclick='NewItem2(event,this.href);return false;'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get List GUID by following this link

[jquery-spservice-get-list-guid/](http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/jquery-spservice-get-list-guid/)

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="../ICTLibrary/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="../ICTLibrary/jquery.SPServices-0.5.4.min.js"></script> 
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> $("document").ready(function() { 
>
> function GetListId(listName) {
> var id = "";
> $().SPServices({
> operation: "GetList",
> listName: listName,
> async: false,
> completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
> id = $(xData.responseXML).find("List").attr("ID");
> }
> });
> return id;
> } 
>
> var listid = GetListId("Plastic");
> if(listid!=null)
> {
> $("#listid").append(listid);
> }
> else
> {
> $("#listid").append("list not found");
> } 
>
> });
> </script>
> <div id="listid" >Plastic list guid: </div>
> ```

Comment: I followed this example before, but neither the attribute "ID" nor any other one has the "ListId" value I am looking for.

Comment: can you add code that your using ?

Comment: I added more detail in my question, thanks for looking :)